# Reading file and defining lines and elements?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm trying to assign the rows to the Capitalized alphabets and columns to the small alphabets, but the second while statement does not print anything for some reason

I tried assigning the rows to numbers but couldn't assign int to Strings.

The Txt File consists of (without spaces between the lines)

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Is it possiable to change an element if given specific row and column?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile {
    private Scanner Reader;
    Scanner Vari = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void openfile(){
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter file location");
            String y = Vari.nextLine();
            Reader = new Scanner(new File(y));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error!!");
        }
    }
    public void readFile(){
        while(Reader.hasNextLine()){
            String a = Reader.nextLine();
            String b = Reader.nextLine();
            String c = Reader.nextLine();
            String d = Reader.nextLine();
            String e = Reader.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("This is the LINE PRint\n");
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c, d,e);
            break;
        }
        while(Reader.hasNext()){
            String A = Reader.next();
            String B = Reader.next();
            String C = Reader.next();
            String D = Reader.next();
            String E = Reader.next();
            System.out.printf("\nCharacter Print ");
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", A, B, C, D,E);
            break;
            }
            
        }

    public void close(){
        Reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show your expected result

Comment: You can easily read your filecontent into a `List<String>` via [FileUtils::readLines](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: @getlost there is no printed result, i'm simply trying to assign rows to lines and col to characters.
For example if i want to print or change 1st row and 3rd col, it would be [b][C]

Comment: @Alexander_Winter if i understand it correctly, it reads the lines and could assign them, but will not assign the characters within the lines

Comment: @Ankosh i didn't understand the line "The Txt File consists of : *without spaces between the lines".could you show the text file

Comment: @getlost the file consist of part is whats inside the txt file

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of simple mistakes in your code, but reading past them, the basic reason your second `while` loop prints nothing, is because you have been through the text file and reached the end. You need some way to reset the file pointer, or buffer, or close and re-open a whole new `Scanner`.

Correcting for this by initialising twice, and correcting the minor errors, this is working code. The question is, is that what you were trying to achieve?

stackoverflow.txt:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

StackOverflow.java:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        new StackOverflow("stackoverflow.txt").readNextLines().close();
        System.out.println();
        new StackOverflow("stackoverflow.txt").readNexts().close();
    }

    private Scanner reader;

    public StackOverflow(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new Scanner( StackOverflow.class.getResourceAsStream( filename ) );
    }

    public StackOverflow readNextLines()
    {
        while (reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String a = reader.nextLine();
            String b = reader.nextLine();
            String c = reader.nextLine();
            String d = reader.nextLine();
            String e = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.printf( "This is the LINE print\n" );
            System.out.printf( "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c, d, e );
            break;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public StackOverflow readNexts()
    {
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
            String A = reader.next();
            String B = reader.next();
            String C = reader.next();
            String D = reader.next();
            String E = reader.next();
            System.out.printf( "Character Print\n" );
            System.out.printf( "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", A, B, C, D, E );
            break;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is the LINE print
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Character Print
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```